# B-field and H-field opposing inside ferromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I was studying Ferromagnets from several books where the authors would just state that its a notable feature of ferromagnets that, in an external B-field, the H-field opposes the B-field inside the magnet of uniform Magnetisation M . I am not entirely convinced on why this would happen especially if I think in terms of the Continuity of the vector fields. Can anyone provide a proof for such a statement? for simplicity you can assume a bar magnet in a uniform B-field to make your argument but feel free to be more general ( even better) !

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demagnetizing_field what is it that you do not understand?

Comment: Although there is a demag field in ferromagnets opposing the external magnetic field, it is not true that the magnetic field inside the ferromagnet always opposes the external field. If you check out the hysteresis loop, e.g. here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/magnetic-hysteresis.html, you will see that in certain cases your statement is correct. Also, keep in mind, B is not really a field, it is a flux density, also called magnetic induction.